# How to classify new word into affinity propagation clusters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis

I was reading through here (first answer):

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups

And I need to figure out how to get the distance of a new word and get the cluster that word best fits into.

```
word_use = #random word here
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([distance.levenshtein(word_use,w1) for w1 in words])
affprop.fit(lev_similarity) 
exemplar = words[affprop.cluster_centers_indices_[cluster_id]]
cluster = np.unique(word_use[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
print("%s: %s" % (exemplar, word_use))
```

This is as much as I've gotten out of it now, but I'm getting an error at the `affprop.fit(lev_similarity)` line:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature 
or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

And in trying to fix it, I did this to that line: `affprop.fit(lev_similarity.reshape(-1, 1))`

But no matter if I do (-1,1) or (1,-1) I get:

```
S must be a square array (shape=(40, 1))
```

or

```
S must be a square array (shape=(1, 40))
```

And I'm lost.

The relevant portion of my code is reproduced below so that you can try it out (random words put in):

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.cluster
import distance
import random
import csv

words = "hi hello yes now please one two three greg test".split(" ") 
words = np.asarray(words)
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])

affprop = sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
for cluster_id in np.unique(affprop.labels_):
    exemplar = words[affprop.cluster_centers_indices_[cluster_id]]
    cluster = np.unique(words[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
    cluster_str = ", ".join(cluster)
    print("%s: %s" % (exemplar, cluster_str))

word_use = "cannon"
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([distance.levenshtein(word_use,w1) for w1 in words])
affprop.fit(lev_similarity.reshape(-1, 1)) 
exemplar = words[affprop.cluster_centers_indices_[cluster_id]]
cluster = np.unique(word_use[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
print(word_use)
print("%s: %s" % (exemplar, word_use))
```

Comment: `fit` would produce a *new* clustering, what you want to do is `transform`, and I am fairly certain that this is not supported. If you'd check the publication, AP like almost any other clustering does not consider the case of labeling "new" data. If you want to classify new data into your clusters, use a **classifier** for that step!

Comment: Well I hoped it'd be easy, oh well. Hmm hmm good idea, I'll just use the lev distances as features for each word and use the initial words as the dataset for the classifier... good stuff, thanks